# subpathsAtPath vs subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath

Tags: ios, swift

What's the difference between `NSFileManager.subpathsAtpath` and `NSFileManager.subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath`?

Both seem to get nested directories and files, and the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/subpathsAtPath:) doesn't say much.

Comment: What happened when you tried them both? Did you get identical results?

Comment: The second performs a deep enumeration

Comment: @tumber033 Fom the docs Because this method recurses the directory’s contents, you might not want to use it in performance-critical code. Instead, consider using the enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler: or enumeratorAtPath: method to enumerate the directory contents yourself. Doing so gives you more control over the retrieval of items and more opportunities to abort the enumeration or perform other tasks at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two methods stand in a historical relationship. The newer one, `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`, explicitly replaces (supersedes) the older one, `subpathsAtPath:`. [To learn this, look in the header file. Apple's documentation is not very good at marking up older, superseded methods as being out of favor.] The historical relationship is not as obvious or as significant in iOS as it would be in Mac OS X, where the newer method appeared in Mac OS X 10.5.

The results may look identical, but they are not:

- The older one, `subpathsAtPath:`, can merely return `nil` to signal a problem. That is why, in Swift, it returns an Optional.
- The newer one, `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:`, also returns (by indirection) an error to describe the problem. That is why, in Swift 2 and later, it is marked `throws`; it does *not* return an Optional, but must be called using `try`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the "subpathsAtpath" is just the older version of that, and now it only needed on OS X 10.5 and later, thats what i have found in docs:

**Special Considerations**
On OS X v10.5 and later, use subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: instead.

The one more reason, is that "subpathsAtpath" returns an optional instead of string array.